# (isset($someValue) && ($someValue != '')) vs. !empty($someValue) - are they the same?

Tags: php, null

Are the below two statements similar?

```
if (isset($someValue) && $someValue != '')
```

and

```
if(!empty($someValue]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of similar except `0` value.

According to https://www.php.net/empty

```
$var = "0";
(!empty($var)) === false;
(isset($var) && $var!='') === true;
```

Comment: Not true: if `$var==="0"`, then `empty($var)===true`. String with zero ('`0`') is one of the values considered empty. The second example `(isset($var) && $var!='')===true` is correct ('`0`' is set, not equal to `null` and different than empty string).

Comment: You're right I forgot the exclamation mark: (!empty($var)) === false;

Comment: Kind of what? I don't get whay you mean actually.

Comment: Like other try to explain, it similar. Meaning in few specific case it's exactly the same. It depends what you want to test. empty() consider the string "0" as an empty string...

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not the same. Yes, they are similar. The first one checks if the 'someValue' is set and not equal to `null` plus whether it is not empty string. The second one is true if `$_GET['act']` is not set or is on the list of variables treated as empty and listed on [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

The following example from the same documentation page should fill any gaps:

```
$var = 0;

// Evaluates to true because $var is empty
if (empty($var)) {
    echo '$var is either 0, empty, or not set at all';
}

// Evaluates as true because $var is set
if (isset($var)) {
    echo '$var is set even though it is empty';
}
```

Comment: Would you give a sample to prove they are not the same i.e. one is `true` and other is `false`?

Comment: I have just did. They are somehow opposite: when the value is not set or is equal to `null`, `isset()` returns `false`, `empty()` returns `true`. In case of other empty values (`0`, `0.0`, '', '`0`' etc.), `isset()` returns `true` and `empty()` also returns `true`.

Answer (score 1):

As you write it, they're actually almost the opposite, but I'll just assume you mean `isset($_GET[someValue])` and `!empty`.

In that case no, they're not the same. In the first line you are checking for an empty string, but for example a zero value would pass. However, a zero value counts as empty.

Comment: & Phoenix Thanks very much! I've updated my question to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Similar but not the same.  Empty will return true if `$_GET['act']` is equal to any of the following:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

Where as the first one only checks to see if the variable has been created and isn't equal to an empty string.

Comment: Would you give a sample to prove they are not the same i.e. one is `true` and other is `false`?

Comment: If you had a number input, and they inputted `0`, the first would return true (set, and not equal to a blank string), whereas empty() would return false.